# Is it true that computability = constructivism + law of excluded middle?

Tags: soft-question, computability, constructive-mathematics

It seems to me that (classical) computable mathematics and constructive mathematics follow roughly the same program, i.e. only working with objects which can explicitly be constructed (by an algorithm, etc.). A key difference, of course, is that constructivism rejects the law of excluded middle over infinite sets, while classical computability (presumably) makes full use of it.

So, would a fair characterisation of the two be that
$$\mathsf{computability}\ =\ \mathsf{constructivism}\ +\ \mathsf{law\ of\ excluded\ middle}$$
Are there any other key differences between these two ways of thinking?

Comment: Is constructivism with the law of the excluded middle just classical mathematics? Moreover, compatibility and recursive mathematics is not everything of constructive mathematics.

Comment: @HanulJeon: it is true that *intuitionistic logic* + LoEM = classical *logic*, but the same cannot be said for constructive / classical mathematics (e.g. classical math includes AC). What would be an example of something in constructive mathematics which is not recursive?

Comment: As far as I know, constructive mathematics includes intuitionism and Bishop-styled constructive analysis. Both are not recursive mathematics: for example, they do not admit Church's thesis, which states every total function over $\omega$ is recursive.

Comment: @HanulJeon good call. It seems CT is usually added as an axiom to constructive math. So in that case, would  computability + CT = constructivism + LoEM  be a fair characterisation? Also Wiki reckons that $\mathsf{RCA}_0 + \mathsf{CT}$ is consistent.

Comment: I could not certainly say your characterization is true, but it worths mentioning that there are attempts to solve problems in compatibility theory by means of Kleene's realizability over intuitionistic set theory $\mathsf{IZF}$ (See D. C. McCarty's dissertation.)